# how to call javascript variables in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I basically made a program that generates random ball numbers based on how many balls the user wants to display on the screen and then the user has to type in the ball numbers in order and if he guesses it right, he wins or else he loses. However, jQuery is a bit confusing for me. How exactly do I call the `x[i]` variable with its values assigned to it to the jQuery at the bottom of the program? Oh and also, the number of balls and input bars are supposed to display based on the maximun number of balls the user types in but is it really possible for me to use array with html and jQuery? So that if the user types in 3, only 3 inputs get displayed or when he types in 6 only 6 gets displayed? Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
window.onload=draw;
 function draw(){
    var canvas= document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    var id;
    var x;
    var y;
    var r;
    var i;
    var balls=[{"id":1,"x":85,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":2,"x":180,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":3,"x":270,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":4,"x":360,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":5,"x":450,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":6,"x":535,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":7,"x":623,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":8,"x":710,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":9,"x":85,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":10,"x":180,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":11,"x":270,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":12,"x":360,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":13,"x":450,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":14,"x":535,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":15,"x":623,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":16,"x":710,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":17,"x":450,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":18,"x":535,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":19,"x":623,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":20,"x":710,"y":190,"r":40}];
    var texts=[];
      var i;
    for(i=0;i<balls.length;i++){
      texts[i]=i;
    }

    var choose;
    var x=[];
    choose=parseFloat(prompt("enter the number of balls u want to see"));
    for (i=0; i<=choose; i++) {
       x[i]=Math.floor((Math.random() * 19) + 1);
      for (var k=0; k<balls.length; k++) {
        var b=balls[k];
        if(b.id==x[i]){                  /*here is the issue*/
          ctx.fillStyle="#800000";
          ctx.strokeStyle="#000000";
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(b.x,b.y,b.r,0, 2 * Math.PI);
          ctx.stroke();
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
          ctx.fillText(b.id, b.x, b.y);
        }
      }

    }
  }
draw()
</script>
<body>
<div id=leftside" width="900" height="1000" style="border: 2px solid #000000">
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800" style="border: 2px solid #000000">
</canvas>
<div id="rightside" width="300" height="800" style="border 2px solid #000000; float: right;">
<<form name="guessForm" id="guessForm" method="POST" action="">
<label>Enter a number: </label>
<input type="text" name="userNumber" id="userNumber">
<input type="button" id="verifyBtn" value="verify">
</form>
<form name="guessForm" id="guessForm2" method="POST" action="">
<label>Enter a number: </label>
<input type="text" name="userNumber2" id="userNumber2">
<input type="button" id="verifyBtn2" value="verify">
</form>
<form name="guessForm" id="guessForm3" method="POST" action="">
<label>Enter a number: </label>
<input type="text" name="userNumber3" id="userNumber3">
<input type="button" id="verifyBtn3" value="verify">
</form>
<form name="guessForm" id="guessForm4" method="POST" action="">
<label>Enter a number: </label>
<input type="text" name="userNumber4" id="userNumber4">
<input type="button" id="verifyBtn4" value="verify">
</form>
<form name="guessForm" id="guessForm5" method="POST" action="">
<label>Enter a number: </label>
<input type="text" name="userNumber5" id="userNumber5">
<input type="button" id="verifyBtn5" value="verify">
</form>
<form name="guessForm" id="guessForm6" method="POST" action="">
<label>Enter a number: </label>
<input type="text" name="userNumber6" id="userNumber6">
<input type="button" id="verifyBtn6" value="verify">
</form>
<hr>
the result is:
<div id="result" style="font-size: 14px"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#verifyBtn").click(function(){

                if($("#userNumber").val()==x[0]){
                        $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                        $("#result").text("correct");
                    }

                    else{
                        $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                        $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+ x);
                    }

            })
            $("#verifyBtn2").click(function(){

                if($("#userNumber2").val()==x[1]){
                        $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                        $("#result").text("yeah");
                    }   

                    else{
                        $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                        $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+ systemNumber);
                    }

            })
            $("#verifyBtn3").click(function(){

                if($("#userNumber3").val()==x[2]){
                        $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                        $("#result").text("yeah");
                    }   

                    else{
                        $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                        $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+ x);
                    }

            })
            $("#verifyBtn4").click(function(){

                if($("#userNumber4").val()==x[3]){
                        $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                        $("#result").text("yeah");
                    }   

                    else{
                        $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                        $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+ x[3]);
                    }

            })
            $("#verifyBtn5").click(function(){

                if($("#userNumber5").val()==x[4]){
                        $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                        $("#result").text("yeah");
                    }   

                    else{
                        $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                        $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+ x[4]);
                    }

            })
            $("#verifyBtn6").click(function(){

                if($("#userNumber6").val()==x[5]){
                        $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                        $("#result").text("yeah");
                    }   

                    else{
                        $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                        $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+ x[5]);
                    }

            })
    })
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: little sidenote: `var i` is declared twice.

Comment: Firstable - your `x variable` cannot be reach in jQuery section.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really look through your whole code for you. Try to be as specific and generic as possible so others can use your question as well. As for jquery this is how you get the value of an input and store it to variable x.

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" >
      $(function(){
      var x = $('#userNumber').val();
      alert(x);
      });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="text" name="userNumber" id="userNumber" value="5">
      </form>
      <body>
</html>
```

I put in a   $(function(){}); (https://api.jquery.com/ready/) because i want the DOM to be ready or else input is undefined.

Comment: Yea i know how to get it from html but how do u get it from javascript?

Comment: Javascript and Jquery are both same language. They just have different syntax. They can share variables. So try this code:
<script type="text/javascript" >
var x;

document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    x = document.getElementById('userNumber').value; // This is javascript
 alert(x);
}, false );


$(function(){
alert(x);
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Firstable - your `x variable` cannot be reach in jQuery section.
In your code it is a local variable.

Your code is quite messy but `first and dirty` fix you can do and come up to my mind is to make a global variable and at the end of draw function set it's value to be like x

```
window.onload=draw;
var xArr;
```

and then at the end of draw function

```
xArr = x;
```

After that you should replace all "x" occurances in your jQuery code to xArr.

It is fast fix to your code.
And also it is fast fix to get correct number of balls and user input validation.

It should look something like this

```
window.onload=draw;
    var xArr
  var BallsNumber = 0;
 function draw(){
    var canvas= document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    var id;
    var x;
    var y;
    var r;
    var i;

    var balls=[{"id":1,"x":85,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":2,"x":180,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":3,"x":270,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":4,"x":360,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":5,"x":450,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":6,"x":535,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":7,"x":623,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":8,"x":710,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":9,"x":85,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":10,"x":180,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":11,"x":270,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":12,"x":360,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":13,"x":450,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":14,"x":535,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":15,"x":623,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":16,"x":710,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":17,"x":450,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":18,"x":535,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":19,"x":623,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":20,"x":710,"y":190,"r":40}];
    var texts=[];
    for(i=0;i<balls.length;i++){
      texts[i]=i;
    }
        var x=[];
    var choose;



while(true){
    choose=parseFloat(prompt("enter the number of balls u want to see (less than 20)"));
    if(choose < 20){
        break;
    }else{
        alert("Please enter a valid number");
    }
}

while(BallsNumber<choose){
    for (i=0; i<choose; i++) {
       x[i]=Math.floor((Math.random() * 19) + 1);
      for (var k=0; k<balls.length; k++) {

        var b=balls[k];
        if(b.id==x[i]){                  /*here is the issue*/
          ctx.fillStyle="#800000";
          ctx.strokeStyle="#000000";
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(b.x,b.y,b.r,0, 2 * Math.PI);
          ctx.stroke();
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
          ctx.fillText(b.id, b.x, b.y);
          BallsNumber++;
        }
      }

    }
}


    xArr = x;
  }

draw()

    $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#verifyBtn").click(function(){

                if($("#userNumber").val()==xArr[0]){
                        $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                        $("#result").text("correct");
                    }

                    else{
                        $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                        $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+ xArr);
                    }

            })
            $("#verifyBtn2").click(function(){

                if($("#userNumber2").val()==xArr[1]){
                        $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                        $("#result").text("yeah");
                    }   

                    else{
                        $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                        $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+ systemNumber);
                    }

            })
            $("#verifyBtn3").click(function(){

                if($("#userNumber3").val()==xArr[2]){
                        $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                        $("#result").text("yeah");
                    }   

                    else{
                        $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                        $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+ xArr);
                    }

            })
            $("#verifyBtn4").click(function(){

                if($("#userNumber4").val()==x[3]){
                        $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                        $("#result").text("yeah");
                    }   

                    else{
                        $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                        $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+ xArr[3]);
                    }

            })
            $("#verifyBtn5").click(function(){

                if($("#userNumber5").val()==x[4]){
                        $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                        $("#result").text("yeah");
                    }   

                    else{
                        $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                        $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+ xArr[4]);
                    }

            })
            $("#verifyBtn6").click(function(){

                if($("#userNumber6").val()==xArr[5]){
                        $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                        $("#result").text("yeah");
                    }   

                    else{
                        $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                        $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+ xArr[5]);
                    }

            })
    })
```

You have a global variable BallsNumber so you can find a solution to make a loop and create a correct number of "verify" inputs